# GroupBy on multiple columns and apply moving function

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose that I have this dataset:

```
Country_id  Company_id  Date    Company_value
1   1   01/01/2018  1
1   1   02/01/2018  0
1   1   03/01/2018  2
1   1   04/01/2018  NA
1   2   01/01/2018  1
1   2   02/01/2018  2
1   2   03/01/2018  NA
1   2   04/01/2018  NA
2   1   01/01/2018  3
2   1   02/01/2018  0
2   1   03/01/2018  2
2   1   04/01/2018  NA
2   2   01/01/2018  1
2   2   02/01/2018  2
2   2   03/01/2018  NA
2   2   04/01/2018  NA
```

and I want to apply a moving function (e.g. moving average) to retrieve an aggregated value for each date and country.

So for example in the case of a moving average (with window = 2 & min_periods=1, NAs not counted in) I would like to have the following:

```
Country_id  Date    Companies_value
1   01/01/2018  1
1   02/01/2018  1
1   03/01/2018  1.33
1   04/01/2018  2
2   01/01/2018  2
2   02/01/2018  1.5
2   03/01/2018  1.33
2   04/01/2018  2
```

To make it easier for you this is calculated in the following way:

```
Country_id  Date    Companies_value
1   01/01/2018  (1+1)/2
1   02/01/2018  (0+1+2+1)/4
1   03/01/2018  (2+0+2)/3
1   04/01/2018  (2)/1
2   01/01/2018  (3+1)/2
2   02/01/2018  (0+3+2+1)/4
2   03/01/2018  (2+0+2)/3
2   04/01/2018  (2)/1
```

How can I do this with `pandas`?

To give a brief example in words, for instance what I want for country 1 at the date 03/01/2018 is to take an average of all the companies' values for this country for the dates 02/01/2018 and 03/01/2018 (in the case of window size 2).

Hence this is what I want to be done for the country 1 at the date 03/01/2018:

```
( Company_value(Company_1, 03/01/2018) + Company_value(Company_1, 02/01/2018) 
+ Company_value(Company_2, 03/01/2018) + Company_value(Company_2, 02/01/2018) ) / 4 =

= ( 2 + 0 + NA + 2) / 4 

= ( 2 + 0 + 2) / 3 # NAs not counted in

= 1.33
```

Analogously, the same I want to be done for the all the dates of each country.

As I said I would like to do the same with my own moving functions beyond the moving average of `pandas` so it would be good to provide a solution which is valid for any custom function.

Comment: check out the combo `DataFrame.rolling` and `apply`

Comment: @Yuca, I know man but I want the exact solution...

Comment: since I don't provide it, that means I don't have the time to actually write it down but at least I can push you in the right direction

Comment: @Yuca, I appreciate it but apparently I knew about the the combo DataFrame.rolling and apply.

Comment: This is not a moving average, with min_period 1 you'd have no value for the first period

Comment: By the way, @jezrael, if you have some free time then I would like to know your opinion on whether the solution below is the optimal one to my problem. Thanks in advance in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated with additional information

*data*:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01']*4,
              'country_id':[1]*8+[2]*8,
              'company_id':[1]*4+[2]*4+[1]*4+[2]*4,
              'value':[1, 0, 2, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 0, 2, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

Create a rolling sum within just `country_id`

```
df['rolling_sum'] = df.groupby('country_id').apply(lambda x: x.value.rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).sum()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Create a rolling count within just `country_id`

```
df['sum_records'] = df.groupby('country_id').apply(lambda x: x.value.rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).count()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now groupby within `country_id` and `date`, to sum the sums, and divide by sum of counts

```
summarized_df = df.groupby(['country_id', 'date']).apply(lambda x: x.rolling_sum.sum()/x.sum_records.sum()).reset_index()

country_id  date      
1           2018-01-01    1.000000
            2018-02-01    1.000000
            2018-03-01    1.333333
            2018-04-01    2.000000
2           2018-01-01    2.000000
            2018-02-01    1.500000
            2018-03-01    1.333333
            2018-04-01    2.000000
```

Lets look at this in further detail. Since we are grouping by country_id, we'll subset out a single country id to practice this methodology on:

if we take just one piece of this, say `country_id == 1`:

```
df2 = df[df['country_id'] == 1]

         date  country_id  company_id  value
0  2018-01-01           1           1    1.0
1  2018-02-01           1           1    0.0
2  2018-03-01           1           1    2.0
3  2018-04-01           1           1    NaN
4  2018-01-01           1           2    1.0
5  2018-02-01           1           2    2.0
6  2018-03-01           1           2    NaN
7  2018-04-01           1           2    NaN
```

If we want the rolling averages for this one, we can just do:

```
df2.value.rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean()
0    1.0
1    0.5
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    1.0
5    1.5
6    2.0
7    NaN
```

We can see here that the values from our subset country_id == 1 dataframe and how they relate to the rolling averages:

```
0    1.0  = (1)/1 = 1
1    0.0  = (0 + 1)/2 = 0.5
2    2.0  = (2 + 0)/2 = 1
3    NaN  = (Nan + 2)/1 = 2
4    1.0  = (1 + Nan)/1 = 1
5    2.0  = (2 + 1)/2 = 1.5
6    NaN  = (Nan + 2)/1 = 2
7    NaN  = (Nan + Nan)/0 = Nan
```

This is how we get our rolling averages for a single grouping of `country_id`

*If* we wanted to get groupings by date, and we went the route of grouping it first by country_id, then date, a single group would look like:

```
df3 = df[(df['country_id'] == 1) & (df['date'] == '2018-03-01')]

df3.value
2    2.0
6    NaN

df3.value.rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean()
2    2.0
6    2.0

df3.value
2    2.0 = (2)/1 = 2
6    NaN = (Nan + 2)/1 = 2
```

The problem here, is that you want the rolling averages *first* by `country_id`, not grouping with `date`. *Then* after you find the rolling averages by country, you want to take *those* values and average them. If we were to take the rolling *averages*, and then *average* those, it would come out incorrect.

So lets go back to the original rolling averages we created for `country_id == 1`, and look at the dates:

```
2018-01-01    1.0  = (1)/1 =         1
2018-02-01    0.0  = (0 + 1)/2 =     0.5
2018-03-01    2.0  = (2 + 0)/2 =     1
2018-04-01    NaN  = (Nan + 2)/1 =   2
2018-01-01    1.0  = (1 + Nan)/1 =   1
2018-02-01    2.0  = (2 + 1)/2 =     1.5
2018-03-01    NaN  = (Nan + 2)/1 =   2
2018-04-01    NaN  = (Nan + Nan)/0 = Nan
```

Now the tricky part here is that at this point we can't just average them together because for example, if you look at 2018-03-01 rolling average values, we have 1 and 2 which is 3. dividing that by 2 would give us 1.5.

We have to first *sum* the rolling values, and then divide by the count of records.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but to be honest I am quite confused with what you do not understand. Firstly, I think it is already clear that I want a (moving) average which averages all the values of the stores within a time-window WITHIN  each country. Secondly, regarding your remark "all 4 data points for 04/01/2018 all have NA for the value, so I'm confused as to how you're getting (2)/1 = 2", the window is of length 2 so apparently it is getting into consideration also the data points for 03/01/2018 where the 2 value is.

Comment: Thirdly, regarding your remark "there are multiple values in your example i.e. some are (1+1)/2 for 2 entries, and others are (1+0+1+2)/4 for 4 entries denote that this is not in fact moving average", the number of entries are different because firstly the NAs values are not apparently counted in the average and secondly for the date 01/01/2018 which is the first date in the dataset then the rolling window for each company is essentially of size one since there are not dates before this date. This is  also how `pandas.DataFrame.rolling` if you test it with one simple example.

Comment: The only difference is that essentially I want to use the moving function in a GroupBy way which makes things a bit more intricate.

Comment: By the way, your solutions make much sense and this is what I did for the very first time. But funnily enough this is not exactly what I want. For example, what I want for country 1 at the date 03/01/2018 is to take an average of all the companies' values for this country for the dates 02/01/2018 and 03/01/2018 (in the case of window size 2). Please see also my edit post for more information.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit Ahhh. I understand. The last explanation addition made sense. I think there was a gap there. I've updated my answer to fix your problem

Comment: No worries :) . Your solution looks good now (upvote) even though perhaps some explanatory notes would be useful at each intermediate step. Let me please have a more thorough look at it please.

Comment: use the df I created, and step through each step and then investigate the output. happy to explain more what's happening if you need.

Comment: Ok each step of your solution makes sense. Essentially you are building step by step the moving average. In this regard, I am wondering if this could be done directly like at your previous solution (`df.groupby(['country_id', 'date']).apply(lambda x: x['value'].rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean()).reset_index()`) and if not, as I also think, why? *(I know that the output of your previous solution was considerably different because I have tested too but I am not sure why)*

Comment: I mean you can print out the statement you wrote right there an see what it does. Its not the same thing. 
I'm not doing step by step the moving average. The moving average is done in the first step. 
The reason this question was confusing is because you want a moving average within one group, and then _after_ you want to group by _another_ group and average those out. The problem is that you want the averages to be from the first group.

Comment: Haha I saw the output but I am not sure what and why is done exactly under the hood.

Comment: I just added a larger explanation. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Cool thanks for that even though I am not sure that this directly explains what `df.groupby(['country_id', 'date']).apply(lambda x: x['value'].rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean()).reset_index()` does and why is not working` but perhaps it answers it indirectly.

Comment: Matt, I have another question for you regarding this :) , how can I make the rolling window to run only based on the dates? By this I mean that if for example window_size=3 then I want the window to run on 3 days length no matter how many observations (e.g. stock values etc) there are in these 3 days. At your solution, the window is running based on each observation which is a distinct stock value but I want this to run based on the dates column. Does this make sense?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit I'm not sure what you mean. Can you create a new post with an example of the output you're looking for? Or edit the bottom of this one with an updated expected output?

Comment: Yes, no worries :) . Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54923831/9024698.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result you want to the following way:

```py
# get company value by date
avg = df.groupby(["Country_id", "Date", "Company_id"]).sum().unstack(level=2).loc[:, "Company_value"]
avg = pd.concat([avg, avg.shift(1)], axis=1)
avg["sum"] = avg.apply("sum", axis=1)

# get company count by date
counts = df.groupby(["Country_id", "Date"]).count().loc[:, "Company_value"]
counts2 = counts + counts.shift(1)

# get the "mean"
result = avg["sum"] / counts2.fillna(counts)
```