# GroupBy on multiple columns and apply moving function based on date column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose that I have this dataset:

```
Store_id    Order_id    Date    Order_value
1   1   01/01/2018  1
1   4   02/01/2018  0
1   5   02/01/2018  2
1   6   02/01/2018  1
1   8   03/01/2018  2
1   9   03/01/2018  NA
2   2   01/01/2018  3
2   3   01/01/2018  2
2   7   02/01/2018  NA
2   10  03/01/2018  1
2   11  03/01/2018  2
2   12  03/01/2018  NA
```

and I want to apply a moving function (e.g. moving average) to retrieve an aggregated value for each store and date.

So for example in the case of a moving average (with window = 2 & min_periods=1, NAs not counted in) I would like to have the following:

```
Store_id    Date    Orders_value
1   01/01/2018  1
1   02/01/2018  1
1   03/01/2018  1.25
2   01/01/2018  2.5
2   02/01/2018  2.5
2   03/01/2018  1.5
```

To make it easier for you this is calculated in the following way:

```
Store_id    Date    Orders_value
1   01/01/2018  (1)/1
1   02/01/2018  (1+2+0+1)/4
1   03/01/2018  (NA+2+1+2+0)/5
2   01/01/2018  (2+3)/2
2   02/01/2018  (NA+2+3)/3
2   03/01/2018  (NA+2+1+NA)/4
```

and because I do not count in NAs then this is it:

```
Store_id    Date    Orders_value
1   01/01/2018  (1)/1
1   02/01/2018  (1+2+0+1)/4
1   03/01/2018  (2+1+2+0)/4
2   01/01/2018  (2+3)/2
2   02/01/2018  (2+3)/2
2   03/01/2018  (2+1)/2
```

which gives the results which you saw above.

How can I do this with `pandas`?

To give a brief example in words, for instance what I want for store 1 at the date 03/01/2018 is to take an average of all the orders' values for this store for the dates 02/01/2018 and 03/01/2018 (in the case of window size 2).

Hence this is what I want to be done for the store 1 at the date 03/01/2018:

```
( Orders_value(Order_1_value + Order_2_value + ... + Order_n_value , 03/01/2018) + Orders_value(Order_1_value + Order_2_value + ... + Order_m_value , 02/01/2018) ) / (n + m) =

# n & m in Order_n_value & Order_m_value refers to the number of the order for this day at this store - not at the order id of the particular order

= ( Orders_value(Order_1_value, 03/01/2018) + Orders_value(Order_2_value, 03/01/2018) +  Orders_value(Order_1_value, 02/01/2018) + Orders_value(Order_2_value, 02/01/2018) + Orders_value(Order_3_value, 03/01/2018) ) / (2 + 3)

= ( NA + 2 + 1 + 2 + 0 ) / 5

= ( 2 + 1 + 2 + 0) / 4 # NAs not counted in

= 1.25
```

Analogously, the same I want to be done for the all the dates of each store.

As I said I would like to do the same with my own moving functions beyond the moving average of `pandas` so it would be good to provide a solution which is valid for any custom function.

Please keep in mind that I have asked a quite similar question recently ([GroupBy on multiple columns and apply moving function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54792538/9024698)) so you may have a look at it if you need some inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! You need to use [time-aware](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/computation.html#time-aware-rolling) `rolling`.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst=True)
temp_df = df.set_index('Date').groupby('Store_id')['Order_value'].rolling(
        '2d', min_periods=1).mean().reset_index()
temp_df.groupby(['Store_id', 'Date']).last()


                Order_value
Store_id    
      Date  
1   2018-01-01          1.00
    2018-01-02          1.00
    2018-01-03          1.25
2   

    2018-01-01          2.50
    2018-01-02          2.50
    2018-01-03          1.50
```

You can also replace `mean` with `apply` and use a custom function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, are you sure that this works? Firstly, you do not generate a value for store 2 at 2018-01-02. Secondly, I am getting this: `raise ValueError("window must be an integer")
ValueError: window must be an integer` when I am trying to use `'2d'` as a window size.

Comment: See again my post for store 2; it is not NA at the final output hence probably you are missing something fundamental here (P.S. A ok now it is better). Yes, it is datetime type; but to be honest I am not using your exact source code but I am modifying the one from the previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/54792538/9024698) so that I am more consistent.

Comment: By the way, also dropping the .dropna() did not work. I am getting an NA now at the final output for store 2 and 2018-02-01.

Comment: Well that's why it's not working. My code was carefully designed around the example you gave. Time-aware rolling only works if you have a 1) monotonically sorted 2) datetime-type index. If you do it differently you will get the error you mentioned

Comment: Yes, now only with your sourcecode and the data snippet above, it does not work.

Comment: Store_id Date                   
1        2018-01-01          1.0
         2018-02-01          1.0
         2018-03-01          2.0
2        2018-01-01          2.5
         2018-02-01          NaN
         2018-03-01          1.5

Comment: That's not what I get. What Pandas version do you have?

Comment: I am using the 0.23.4 version.

Comment: Ok now it is actually running correctly (upvote). I had not included the `dayfirst=True` before.

Answer (score -1):

I can't quite figure out your need from your question but if all you're looking for
is a simple way to apply custom functions to rolling windows in pandas try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=myData)
df['newColumnName'] = df['DataColumnName'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: myFunction(x))
```

Comment: I can't even figure out how it's different. You litterally copy/pasted the question. Do you mean you want to average the dates?

Comment: Someone else will understand it; thank you for your time.